# Getting android view inflate exception after upgrading gradle version 3.6.0 to the latest 4.1.0(Exception occurs only when updating the app)

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle, material-components-android, android-appbarlayout

I am Getting an android view inflate exception after upgrading Gradle version 3.6.0  to the latest 4.1.0. This happens only when upgrading from the existing version to a new version. Everything works fine for fresh installs.

```
<com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
                    
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                
                    <RelativeLayout
                        android:id="@+id/toolbarrel"
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize">
                        <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
                            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                            android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
                            app:titleTextColor="?attr/titleColor"
                            android:paddingLeft="?attr/actionBarSize"
                            />
                      </RelativeLayout>
                
                
</com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout>
```

Stack trace

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException
Unable to start activity
ComponentInfo{com.com.xxx.xxxxx/com.xxx.xxxxx.MainActivity}:
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #29 in
com.xxx.xxxxx:layout/activity_main: Binary XML file line
#29 in com.xxx.xxxxx:layout/activity_main: Error
inflating class com.google.android.material.appbar.AppBarLayout
android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3654)
android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:3806)
android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute
(LaunchActivityItem.java:83)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks
(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute
(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:2267)
android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:107)
android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:237)
android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:8167)
java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Method.java)
com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run
(RuntimeInit.java:496)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:1100)
Caused by android.view.InflateException
```

Comment: Hi, you're going to have to share the stack trace.

Comment: Do you have `androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1...` in your gradle?

Comment: @HB. Yes I do have the latest version(1.2.0)

Comment: Try `invalidate cache and restart`

Comment: @EugenPechanec added stack trace

Comment: @HB. Thanks for the reply. There are no errors in the android studio. The project just compiles fine.

Comment: You're going to add the rest of the stack trace too.  There are ~3 chained exceptions.